# Error 800A0400 for ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$CV$749").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlNo

Tags: excel, vbscript, macros

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set Excel2= objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\DBG\Temp.xlsm")
Excel2.Worksheets("output").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$CV$749").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlNo
```

if i try to execute above code I get error .Thanks in advance

```
Line 35
Char 60
Error Expected statement
Code 800A0400
```

How can I resolve this issue

Comment: You don't have a line 35, only 1 to 5. Therefore it is a mystery error.

Comment: Please read this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for information on how to write a good question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use neither named parameters (e.g. `Columns:=`) nor Excel.Application constants (e.g. `xlNo`) in a VBS script. The parameters you used (e.g. `Columns:=` and `Header:=`) in the [Range.RemoveDuplicates method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823.aspx) are the only two allowed and `xlNo` resolves to 2.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set Excel2= objExcel.Workbooks.Open("t:\tmp\Temp.xlsm")
Excel2.Worksheets("output").Activate
Excel2.ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$CV$749").RemoveDuplicates 2, 2
```

The [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx) needs to reference its parent [Excel Application object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx) as well.