# VBScript: How to copy a range of cells as an Image and Paste it via a Bookmark into Word

Tags: excel, ms-word, vbscript

I try to copy a Range of Cells from an Excel Worksheet into a Word Document on a specific Bookmark.
Additional a resize would be great but I don't come so far. If it's necessary to mention I don't want to have a Visible Word or Excel (because I saw it on some Code and don't know if it's mandatory).
Here the Code:

```
Set ObjWkBk = ObjXl.Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xlsx")

Set ObjWd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set ObjDoc = ObjWd.Documents.Add("C:\test.docx")

Set xlRange =  ObjWkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D4").Select

Set wdRange = ObjDoc.Bookmarks("Ending").Range

xlRange.CopyPicture
wdRange.Paste

ObjDoc.SaveAs ("C:\test1.docx")

ObjDoc.Close: ObjWd.Quit: ObjWkBk.Close: ObjXl.Quit
Set ObjDoc = Nothing: Set ObjWd = Nothing: Set ObjWkBk = Nothing: Set ObjXl = Nothing
```

The Error is the following:
Error: Expected Statement
Code: 800A0400

Comment: And the error appears on which line?

Comment: Sorry, on Line: 11 and Char: 32. @JohnKorchok

Comment: Related: [pasting from excel into a word document](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6310258)

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36254535/1682881

Comment: @Flakes but here it is no Picture used.

Comment: @user692942 but this is VBA and Clipboard usage...

Comment: Just wanted to point out you cannot use named parameters like Appearance:= in vbscript.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42194300/1682881

Comment: @Flakes okay, thanks I didn't recognize it. Alright, one step further. Now I get the Error in Line 7. It looks like it doesn't like the ```.Select``` part.

Comment: You should mention what exactly the error message is. Maybe you don't need the select at ll? its the range you need.

Comment: @Flakes Alright, here the Error Message: Line: 7 Column: 1 Error: Object required: 'Obj.WkBk.Worksheets(...).Range(...).Select' Code: 800A01A8 Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error System: This directory contains entries whose names differ only in case.

Comment: Ahhhhh, you're right. I suggested it's necessary for the Picture, but it's working also without. Awesome, thank you! @Flakes